# maven - Instruct mvn to find POM upon the path

Tags: java, maven

Possibily a stupid question. I have done searches with terms come up with me.

Is there an option or workaround which makes `mvn` preforms like `ant -s`.

```
(ant help)
  -find <file>           (s)earch for buildfile towards the root of
    -s  <file>           the filesystem and use it
```

It is very frequent that I walk deep into my project to change source file and want to run an instant compilation with the same terminal. But without `cd` back to the root of project, mvn only yells "but there is no POM in this directory". :(

Comment: Yes, it is the `-f` switch to specify a POM. Refer to the linked question.

Comment: @Tunaki Got it, thanks. :3